# How to hide query string when redirect to a page in another website

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
        var url = string.Format("{0}?userid={1}&password ={2}", rootUrl, Id,password);

        //use ClientScript to open a new windows from server side
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("window.open('");
        sb.Append(url);
        sb.Append("');");
        sb.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", sb.ToString());
```

I don't want to userid and password display in url.

Comment: This is fail on so many levels...why would you ever even have an un-encrypted user password?

Comment: Does the page you're trying to open belong to the same application?

Comment: I get the feeling we're on Step 5 of something, and you made a mistake back on Step 2.  I can't imagine a scenario where you would even need to do this.

Comment: scenario why I need such a solution. I have a web application A, in A application, user can enter order ID, the order belongs to different companies, A application need map orderid and company then open that company's website(pass orderid and user info) on new tab on current browser.

Comment: So the password and username are required or not?

Comment: username and password are required otherwise when redirecting, will transfer to login page.

Answer (score 5):

You should do it using the [HTTP POST request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) since the posted content is not visible with that method, it's embeded in the HTTP message body and exposed as query string parameters.

And as @YuriGalanter commented, do it with [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL) (HTTPS), in order to encrypt your messages over the network traffic and in turn, to prevent from sniffers to see the sensitive details.

For example:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWReq =
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://domain.com/page.aspx");

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = "username=user";
postData += "&password=pass";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

And to get the response:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Post data can also be viewed.. so it is dangrous too

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli This is why the SSL was invented.

Comment: Thanks everyone, post is good enough for now, but with this solution, how to open the new page in current browser's new tab?

Answer (score 0):

It looks best way to hide user info is encrypt query string when passing them to another site and open that url in new tab in current browser.